# How can I return all numeric values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I had to select from the column all the values that contain numbers (NULL values aren't interested). How can I make a query to my table using something like this:

```
SELECT c1
FROM t1 
WHERE c1 ...;
```

I tried to find suitable regular expressions, which are popular in many imperative programming languages, but they didn't fit for PostgreSQL, unfortunately (or I used them incorrectly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
SELECT c1 FROM t1 WHERE c1 ~ '^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$';
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

```
SELECT
    fld
FROM (
    VALUES ('1'),
        ('test1'),
        ('34'),
        ('dog'),
        ('3cat')) AS t (fld)
WHERE
    regexp_match(fld, '^[[:digit:]]{1,}$') IS NOT NULL;

fld 
-----
 1
 34
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the third value (in example) is "34", this query returns "{3}", but I need "34". The above answer from M. Kuz. looks true.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
SELECT c1 FROM t1 WHERE c1 ~ '[0-9]';
```

From this table named STACKOVERFLOW:

| id_stack | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Niklaus Wirth |
| 2 | Bjarne Stroustrup |
| 3 | Linus Torvalds |
| 4 | Donald Knuth |
| 5 | C3PO |
| 6 | R2D2 |
| 7 | ZX Spectrum +3 |

The Query SELECT NAME FROM STACKOVERFLOW WHERE NAME ~ '[0-9]'; will return:

| name |
| --- |
| C3PO |
| R2D2 |
| ZX Spectrum +3 |

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> ~ 'PRF:\d{11}-\d{4}'
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?